# How to get the position of a row in a listview?

Tags: android, android-listview

Can anyone help me How can I store the value position of a row from listview when clicked? 
I want to use the value in onPostExecute on another class.
Thanks for your time in advance.
Here is my code.

```
 @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if (view == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.model, viewGroup, false);
        }
       ...
        final Pending s = (Pending) this.getItem(i);
       ...

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

*//here is where I want to get the position to use on my updateData()'s onPostExecute*

                final String id = 2;
                String link = "http://abcabcabc.com/abc.php?id=" + id;
                new updateData().execute(link);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
```

also, how can I call it in onPostExecute to display some data?

Comment: you can get it from your adapter class.

Comment: @MdMobinurRahman I now get the value of the row. can you suggest me away how to use it in my onPostExecute? Thanks in advance. And is it possible to store it in the Log.i? I'm sorry.I'm new to this.

Answer (score 1):

The position of the row is the parameter `i` in your `getView` method:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    //i is the position of the row
}
```

In order to use the position of the row in the `onPostExecute` method of an `AsyncTask`, you will need to pass the row position as a parameter to your "updateData" class.

However, the issue is that an `AsyncTask` can only take in one type of data as a parameter, and currently it is only able to accept Strings.

To get around this and be able to pass both the URL (a String) and the id/row position (an int), you could create a class (with a better name that represents what you're doing with the link):

```
public class DetailLink {
    private String link;
    private int id;

   //getters and setters
}
```

Then, in your "updateData" class, change the `Params` type parameter to be of type `DetailLink` instead of String.  This will mean that your `doInBackground` method will accept a `DetailLink` as a parameter.  In order to store the id so that it can be used the `onPostExecute` method, save it as an instance variable of the "updateData" class.

```
 private class UpdateDataTask extends AsyncTask<DetailLink, Void, Void> {
     private int myId;

     protected void doInBackground(DetailLink... detailLink) {
         myId = detailLink.getId();
         String url = detailLink.getLink();
         //do your task here
     }

     protected void onPostExecute() {
         //do something with the myId instance variable
     }
 }
```

Finally, in your `getView` method, you can create a new DetailLink and pass that to your `execute` method:

```
DetailLink detailLink = new DetailLink();
detailLink.setId(i);
detailLink.setLink(link);
new updateData().execute(detailLink);
```